# Azure Data Factory Storage Event Trigger not starting the pipeline

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, eventtrigger

I have created an Storage Event Trigger to start a pipeline in Azure Data Factory. I know it is well configured, because I can successfully trigger it after uploading a Blob manually through the UI. But using TypeScript with the script below, the blob is created successfully but the event trigger is not working. I've read that we need to use a Flush method, but not sure how it can be done in TypeScript.

Here is the code I am using:

```
import { BlobServiceClient } from "@azure/storage-blob"

async function handleWriteToBlob(blobData, insurance) {
  const jsonData = sendJson(blobData);
  const containerName = "raw-layer";
  const fileName = blobData['timestamp'];
  const blobName = `/folder_name/${insurance}/${insurance}-insurance_form-${fileName.toISOString()}.json`;

  const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net?${sasToken}`);
  const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName)
  const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);

  const options = {
    blobHTTPHeaders: {
      blobContentType: 'application/json'
    },
    bufferThreshold: 4 * 1024 * 1024, // 4MB
    maxBuffers: 20 // 80MB
  };

  const result = await blockBlobClient.upload(
    jsonData,
    jsonData.length,
    options
  );

  if (result.errorCode) {
    throw Error(result.errorCode);
  }

  console.log(`Uploaded BlockBlob ${blobName} successfully as: ${jsonData}`);
}

function sendJson(blobData) {
  console.log(`${JSON.stringify(blobData)}`);
  return JSON.stringify(blobData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I removed the initial "/" from `blobName` the `.upload()` method, was still successful uploading the file to my blob container, but now the trigger was working well!

So it seems like the `@azure/storage-blob` SDK allows to upload with both path implemented, but the difference is in the way it triggers the storage event.

If this doesn't solve your issue, *there are a couple of options, as explained here:*

**Option A (Using Typescript)**

[Create a custom topic in Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/custom-event-quickstart-portal#create-a-custom-topic)

[Create a custom event trigger to run a pipeline in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-custom-event-trigger)

[Use the Azure EventGrid Node Package to publish your event, once you upload the file, using the same code as in my question](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/eventgrid)

**Option B (Use REST API)**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage?tabs=event-grid-event-schema

*Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated*

Triggered when a blob is created or replaced.Specifically, this event is triggered when clients use the PutBlob, PutBlockList, or CopyBlob operations that are available in the Blob REST API and when the Block Blob is completely committed.